# Area calculation in Google Static Map API

Tags: android, google-maps-static-api

How is area calculated using Google Static map API?
After passing the Latitude and Longitude of a plot to the google Static map API, what we get is the final result.
How is this obtained?
How is it calculated, is there any formulae which is applied?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a way to directly compute the are, ut firs step is to compute meters per pixels . You can accomplish that if you know map dimensions in pixels and level of zoom , i'm not sure if my calculations are right , but at 45 degrees latitude(north) the scale  0.88 meters per pixel at zoom level 20  , and then this unit doubles with level of zoom ...(ex. at level 19 scale is 0.88*2 , at 18 ..0.88*4 ..etc)